# Webpage times out before a postgresql query has finished compiling the results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have an action that gathers the totals from millions of records that is timing out. The page expires before the results. The report probably completes in 30 seconds or so. I am on Heroku. I use rails 4 with Postgres. I am a newbie to Rails so go easy on me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's hard to give general performance advice. Do you have any logger output from the offending action? Can you add more details about the models/controller involved?

Answer (score 0):

For time-consuming query, we usually don't let the action do the query.
There are some strategies, but I just think 2 solutions here:

1. Do the query on background, then notify the web client via websocket, eg we can use [pusher](https://rubygems.org/gems/pusher) for that
2. Do aggregate calculation with whatever strategy (in the end of day/ receive new data,.etc), when we receive a request, just return the aggregate result